# Swift 2.0 / UITableViewCell - cant get action to happen in cell in top position when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

My goal is to be able to auto scroll through my UITableView cells while automatically performing an action on the cell that is in the top visible position in the view.  I've already figured out how to auto scroll through my UITableView using the various scrollview delegate methods, but im still having trouble figuring out how to call an action on the desired cell once it's in the correct position in the feed.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what do u mean by `once it's in the correct position in the feed.`. Do you want it to happen once scrolling has finished or while the table is scrolling.

Comment: ideally while it's scrolling but either will work.

Comment: are your cells fixed height

Comment: yup. all the dimensions are fixed

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this :**

```
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:desiredrow inSection:desiredsection];
       [yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

Comment: i can already scroll to the desired row... the issue im having is automatically calling a specific action on the cell once it scrolls there. ie - changing the cells bg color

Comment: @säculnój if you are scrolling to the cell, you already have the index path. Use that index path to get the cell instance e.g. table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

Comment: understood, but ive tried that. could you give me a code example? i realize the fix may be super basic, but ive been trying this for some time now and havent made much progress recently